# Image borders and ResponsiveSlides.js

Tags: jquery, css, border

I would like to add a border to images in a slide show using ResponsiveSlides.js.  While experimenting with the demo page that comes with the ResponsiveSlides.js script, I found adding a border to the images results in the right border not being visible.  The borders on the top, bottom, and left side of the image appear as expected.

Why would the left border of an image not be visible when using ResponsiveSlides.js?

Here is the CSS style rule I added to the demo.html file that comes with the ResponsiveSlides.js script to add a border to the images in the demo:

```
<style type="text/css">
   img { border: 1px solid red ! important; }
</style>
```

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance!

EDIT: Ok, after posting this question, I found adding the border to the unordered list element that ResponsiveSlides.js uses to hold the images causes the border to appear around the images, themselves, as I want.  In this cases, I added:

border: 1px solid black;

to the .rslides class, which is the default class used by ResponsiveSlides.js for slide show containing elements and the border appeared just fine.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm new here so I'm starting the learning curve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found adding the border to the unordered list element that ResponsiveSlides.js uses to hold the images causes the border to appear around the images, themselves, as I want. In this cases, I added:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

to the .rslides class, which is the default class used by ResponsiveSlides.js for the element(s) which contain the slide show and the border appeared just fine.